# How do I drain an input stream I don't want to read?

Tags: node.js, stream

I'm using `tar-stream` to look at the contents of a tar file.  I just want to look at the entries, and I don't want to do anything with the data.  The documentation for this package says:

> The tar archive is streamed sequentially, meaning you must drain each
>   entry's stream as you get them or else the main extract stream will
>   receive backpressure and stop reading.

I have looked at the [stream](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html) documentation, but all I see regarding draining is events which are generated when there is no more data.  I see nothing about how to manually drain an input.  I don't want to just read the data as I'm assuming there is a more efficient way that just skips over all the data and marks it read instead of potentially shuffling hundreds of megabytes through memory for no good reason.

How do I drain an input stream?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The use of the word "drain" in this context can be confusing.  The solution is to call the `resume` function on the input stream. This "can be used to fully consume the data from a stream without actually processing any of that data" per the [example in the documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_resume):

```
getReadableStreamSomehow()
  .resume()
  .on('end', () => {
    console.log('Reached the end, but did not read anything.');
  });
```